# The meaning of "brought up"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is this usage possible and common?

> In order to provide a more accepting and comfortable setting for children with autism or other special needs, AMC movie auditoriums will have their lights **brought up** and the sound turned down, families will be able to bring in their own gluten-free, casein-free snacks, and no previews or advertisements will be shown before the movie. Additionally, audience members are welcome to get up and dance, walk, shout or sing - in other words, AMC’s “Silence is Golden®” policy will not be enforced unless the safety of the audience is questioned. Tickets can be purchased on the day of the event.

Comment: Yes, particularly in theaters. _Bring up the lights_ means to turn the lights on in the auditorium. Therefore, the usage is possible, and it's common in this context. It might be interesting to discuss, say, the difference between _turning on lights_ and _bringing up lights_, but you haven't asked about that.

Comment: It probably comes from the old control switches on the stage lights - giant levers pushed up and down. And if the show is a great success, they'll "bring down the house" ... now, back to your regularly scheduled program ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of cinemas or theatres, yes it is common.  There is perhaps a nuance in that it means the lights are brightened gradually via a dimmer switch, rather than being turned on instantly.

It is also commonly found in the context of how or where an individual was raised in their childhood : "John was brought up by his Aunt and Uncle, mostly in Glasgow, but they moved to Liverpool in his late teenage years".  This may be more common in British English than American.